# Error: option gssapiservicename is not supported

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

mongoose(6.0.12) throw error `Error: option gssapiservicename is not supported`.

Here the code for setting up the mongodb connection :

```
const connectDB = async () => {
try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
    })

    console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`.cyan.underline)
} catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`.red.underline.bold)
    process.exit(1)
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your Mongo URI, it should not have any parameter, eg: `mongodb://localhost:27017`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the parameter in your connection string, newer versions of Clients doesn’t support this anymore